# Error exists after project being imported in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I was working on a Java project on my laptop and then I decided to move it to my PC.

The project was totally ok and had no errors when I was working on it on my laptop but after I imported it to eclipse on my PC eclipse, it has errors; mostly "Cannot be resolved". 

This means the problem is with eclipse and not my code.

I have no idea how to fix this and I'm in a bit of hurry.
Here's a screen shot from my errors
[image]

I found out that the problem is with some imports. Libraries do exist but eclipse doesn't import them. What should I do now?

Comment: your screen shot is not display.

Comment: It's not a photo it's a link : http://8pic.ir/images/4sw1hp52kehfsz228iaq.png

Comment: "Cannot be resolved" does not mean the problem is with Eclipse. The problem might be with your project - is a library missing?

Comment: No I copied all files. Nothing's missing. Maybe the problem is with the library importing. I'll check it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot after copying Eclipse projects (or after updating the local code from a repository), the following steps usually solve the Problem for me and my team:

- Select the Project -> Rightclick -> Refresh
- Go to Project -> "Clean..."

Comment: Sorry. Did you check the linked Libraries? Eclipse links them sometimes with absolute instead of relative paths.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll check it now.